# How to multiply 2 columns in database MySQL using JAVA GUI?

Tags: java, mysql, database, formula

I want to make a sales database that it will insert and insert the data. My id is AUTO INCREMENT.

My Code is Here:

Inserting Data

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO `mycredentials`.`sales` (name, price,quantity)  
VALUES ('"+jFrame_pName.getText()+"', '" + jFrame_pPrice.getText() +  "','"+jFrame_quantity.getText()+"')";
ps.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Updating Data:

```
String sql2 = "UPDATE `mycredentials`.`sales` SET quantity = '"+jFrame_quantity.getText()+"', total = (quantity*price) WHERE id ='?'";
ps.executeUpdate(sql2);
```

And Viewing Data:

```
String sql1 = "SELECT name AS 'Product Name', price AS 'Product Price', quantity as 'Quantity', total as 'Total' FROM  `mycredentials`.`sales`";
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(sql1);
table_1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

But the displays makes the total NULL. What is my error? Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you check (with some database management tool) if the values are correctly saved in the database?

Comment: Yes. They are correctly saved in the database BUT the total is always equal to NULL.

Comment: If you execute your statement inside your tool, does it return correct total? So you could know if there is problem with your SQL or there is something wrong with your Java code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to maybe specify again the quantity like this?

```
String sql2 = "UPDATE `mycredentials`.`sales` SET quantity = '"
  + jFrame_quantity.getText() + "', total = ("
  + jFrame_quantity.getText() + "*price) WHERE id ='?'";

ps.executeUpdate(sql2);
```

Comment: My total is still null.

Comment: Have you tried to print jFrame_quantity.getText()?
Maybe you are not getting any value from the interface.